# how I can return value with a same type using exec.Command().Output()

Tags: go

in the next example, I am using *nodejs* to calculate 1+1 and I want the result with a same type of value, not string

example:

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/nodejs", "-p", "1+1")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err, stderr.String())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(out.String())
}
```

is there way to do that?

Comment: A command can only return a string. If you want a different datatype, you need to parse it yourself. Perhaps by using strconv.ParseInt

Answer (score 2):

When executing a command, you get a string back. You will need to deserialize it to get the proper type back. If you only expect your Node.js command to print numbers, you can use `strconv.ParseFloat`:

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/nodejs", "-p", "1+1")
    b, err := cmd.Output()
    v, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(b), 64)
    fmt.Println(v) // v is of type float64
}
```

If you want to handle more complex types such as javascript objects and array, I suggest serializing/deserializing node's result using JSON:

```
type Result struct {
    Value float64
    Args []float64
}
func main() {
    var result Result
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/nodejs", "-p", `JSON.stringify({"value": 1+1, "args": [1, 1]})`)
    b, err := cmd.Output()
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &r)
    fmt.Println(r.Value)
}
```